# Wait .5 seconds before continuing code VB.net

Tags: vb.net, wait

I have a code and I want it to wait somewhere in the middle before going forward.
After the WebBrowser1.Document.Window.DomWindow.execscript("checkPasswordConfirm();","JavaScript")
I want it to wait .5 seconds and then do the rest of the code.

```
    WebBrowser1.Document.Window.DomWindow.execscript("checkPasswordConfirm();","JavaScript")

    Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All
    For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements
        If webpageelement.InnerText = "Sign Up" Then
            webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: How do you know that will be long enough?

Comment: Because I've tested it. And that seems enough, but a when the java script function completes would be better.

Comment: What if my Internet connection is slower? Or my computer's JavaScript interpreter? My point is, assuming a particular time value is rarely a good solution. Certainly not a robust one.

Comment: @koolboy5783: So you found an empirical evidence that this solution works for your case. It does not prove, however, that it will work in the long run. And, as Cody mentioned, it will most likely break soon after. If you are waiting on the event, you better indicate this in code - it will be easier to debug and troubleshoot as well.

Answer (score 60):

You'll need to use [System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(number of milliseconds)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx).

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Window.DomWindow.execscript("checkPasswordConfirm();","JavaScript")

Threading.Thread.Sleep(500) ' 500 milliseconds = 0.5 seconds

Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All
For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements
    If webpageelement.InnerText = "Sign Up" Then
        webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Whenever I do that the program freezes first, and then it does the code.

Comment: I know. You have two options, either freeze the thread, or, use a timer (chipperyman573's suggestion)...

Comment: I'm using on a VB.NET winform application and this does not cause my program to crash.  I am waiting for a SQL update to finish but like @Neolisk mentions, event handling is probably the best way to go about this.  Think I might need to create a question to address this since I do not see any posted on StackOverflow at the moment.

Answer (score 17):

This question is old but here is another answer because it is useful fo others:

**thread.sleep** is not a good method for waiting, because usually it freezes the software until finishing its time, this function is better:

```
   Imports VB = Microsoft.VisualBasic

   Public Sub wait(ByVal seconds As Single)
     Static start As Single
     start = VB.Timer()
     Do While VB.Timer() < start + seconds
       System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
     Loop
   End Sub
```

The above function waits for a specific time without freezing the software, however increases the CPU usage.

This function not only doesn't freeze the software, but also doesn't increase the CPU usage:

```
   Private Sub wait(ByVal seconds As Integer)
     For i As Integer = 0 To seconds * 100
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
       Application.DoEvents()
     Next
   End Sub
```

Comment: The value of second in wait function parameter will be in second or millicond?

Comment: @SunnySandeep it's in seconds, because the if `seconds = 2` we would loop `2 * 100 = 200` times and `200 * 10 (the value in Sleep(..)) = 2000` which in total is 2 seconds in milliseconds.

Comment: Timers.Timer is good when there aren't many instances of Timers.Timer. Also, it is easy to implement. But if there is a need to use multiple Timers.Timer, the execution slows down. For such situations, Thread.Wait() (Little complicated to implement) is a good idea. I say this with experience.

Answer (score 5):

```
Imports VB = Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Sub wait(ByVal seconds As Single)
    Static start As Single
    start = VB.Timer()
    Do While VB.Timer() < start + seconds
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
    Loop
End Sub
```

%20+ high cpu usage + no lag

```
Private Sub wait(ByVal seconds As Integer)
    For i As Integer = 0 To seconds * 100
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
        Application.DoEvents()
    Next
End Sub
```

%0.1 cpu usage + high lag

Answer (score 4):

Make a timer, that activates whatever code you want to when it ticks. Make sure the first line in the timer's code is:

```
timer.enabled = false
```

Replace timer with whatever you named your timer.

Then use this in your code:

```
   WebBrowser1.Document.Window.DomWindow.execscript("checkPasswordConfirm();","JavaScript")
timer.enabled = true
Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All
For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements
    If webpageelement.InnerText = "Sign Up" Then
        webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Static tStart As Single, tEnd As Single, myInterval As Integer
myInterval = 5 ' seconds
tStart = VB.Timer()
tEnd = myInterval + VB.Timer()
Do While tEnd > tStart
    Application.DoEvents()
    tStart = VB.Timer()
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had better results by checking the browsers readystate before continuing to the next step. This will do nothing until the browser is has a "complete" readystate

```
Do While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> 4
''' put anything here. 
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `Threading.Thread.SLeep(2000)` is that it executes first in my VB.Net program. This

```
Imports VB = Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Sub wait(ByVal seconds As Single)
    Static start As Single
    start = VB.Timer()
    Do While VB.Timer() < start + seconds
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
    Loop
End Sub
```

worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested Code is flawed:

```
Imports VB = Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Sub wait(ByVal seconds As Single)
    Static start As Single
    start = VB.Timer()
    Do While VB.Timer() < start + seconds
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
    Loop
End Sub
```

VB.Timer() returns the seconds since midnight. If this is called just before midnight the break will be nearly a full day.
I would suggest the following:

```
Private Sub Wait(ByVal Seconds As Double, Optional ByRef BreakCondition As Boolean = False)
    Dim l_WaitUntil As Date
    l_WaitUntil = Now.AddSeconds(Seconds)
    Do Until Now > l_WaitUntil
        If BreakCondition Then Exit Do
        DoEvents()
    Loop
End Sub
```

BreakCondition can be set to true when the waitloop should be cancelled as DoEvents is called this can be done from outside the loop.

Comment: This works much better than the sleep() approach, which has way to much lag.  For a 2 second delay  in process time, this method works immediately, where 2 seconds using the sleep approach resulted in about a 10 second delay.  In addition, I have a timer set with 5000 milliseconds delay for another subroutine that has to fire every 5 seconds to check something, and with the delay, I think the 10 second delay was equal to the 2 seconds I used for the sleep-based approach times the 5 second (5000 msec) timer delay.   I think they interacted behind the scenes and caused longer lag.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use [System.Threading.ManualResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent?view=netframework-4.8)

```
dim SecondsToWait as integer = 5
Dim Waiter As New ManualResetEvent(False)
Waiter.WaitOne(SecondsToWait * 1000) 'to get it into milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub WaitFor(Secs As Integer)
    Dim StartTime As DateTime = TimeOfDay
    Dim EndTime As DateTime = DateAdd(DateInterval.Second, Secs, StartTime)
    Do While StartTime < EndTime
        StartTime = TimeOfDay
    Loop
End Sub
```

Of course, this only works for full seconds, not partial secs.

Comment: Given the question was for 0.5 seconds - would have been better to suggest a solution that dealt with milliseconds not full seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000) and import Threading the wait for 5 seconds.

Answer (score -2):

VB.net
4.0 framework 
Code :

`Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)`

The integer is in miliseconds ( 1 sec = 1000 miliseconds)

I did test it and it works

Comment: He asked for 0.5 seconds so it should be `.Sleep(500)` :)