# How can I open cmd and send a series of commands in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, shell, cmd

My code is only opening the cmd in the visual studio directory and I do not want that. I'm trying to configure a piece of equipment and it requires a series of commands.  I'm really new to this.

```
    If baudrates.SelectedItem = "150" Then
        Shell("CMD.exe")
        SendKeys.Send("telnet splat-hwa")
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
        SendKeys.Send("lab")
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
        SendKeys.Send("lab")
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
        SendKeys.Send("2")
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
        SendKeys.Send("1")
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
        SendKeys.Send("4")
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
        SendKeys.Send("2")
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
        SendKeys.Send("2")
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")

    End If
```

Comment: Could you verify if CMD becomes active window before your application sends keys into it, please? If this is the reason, [adding a delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857893/wait-5-seconds-before-continuing-code-vb-net/15861154) may be a rough workaround.

Comment: A better solution would be to just communicate with your device directly, skipping the command prompt and Terminal middle-men. This `SendKeys` business is very fragile.

Comment: What does the code do that depends on the current directory? Why is this a problem?

Comment: @Yaruson, to be specific, as soon as "150" is selected in the dropdown CMD becomes an active window.  Then the dropdown has all he commands written inside of it "lablab21422"

Comment: I'm communicating with the device directly through it's device name that's been associated with it's IP address.  The only way to do this is through some type of terminal or unix OS based on my knowledge configuring it remotely. @Cody Gray

Comment: @Liturgist I need CMD to appear as if it where opened from the start menu.  I think the directory effects the commands.  I want to enter CMD as an admn.

Comment: Well, there are terminal libraries available for .NET. I would recommend using one of those, instead of outsourcing the work to the Terminal application since that one is designed for interactive use. Something like this: http://sshnet.codeplex.com/ or perhaps http://www.rebex.net/terminal-emulation.net/. Only you know the details of what will work with your device, but 99% of the time, trying to automate a command prompt is a mistake. Better to invest the effort in doing it the right way.